# How do I have the index of one array influence what the index another will be?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am currently attempting to do as the title states, where I have two arrays,

```
var weapon = ["Stick", "Dagger", "Shortsword", "Longsword", "Magical Sword", "Chunchunmaru"];
```

and

```
var weaponAverageDamage = [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15];
```

I would like to have it so that whatever specific index "weapon" is, weaponAverageDamage would be the same thing. For example, any instances in the program where weapon[1] came up, if a monster's health were being calculated or something, then weaponAverageDamage[1] also would be accessed.

Comment: So use the same index all the time? What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: Define a variable that holds your index. Use it to index both arrays.

Comment: Or use objects `{name: "Dagger", damage: 3}`

Comment: Why isn't this an array of "weapons": `weapons = [{type: "Stick", damage: 0}, {type:"Dagger", damage: 3}, {type="Shortsword", damage: 6}, ...]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Considering the fact that the array `weaponAverageDamage` is sorted according to the corresponding value to each weapon in `weapon` array, we can do this:

```
var weapon = ["Stick", "Dagger", "Shortsword", "Longsword", "Magical Sword", "Chunchunmaru"];
var weaponAverageDamage = [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15];

var weaponIndex = weapon.indexOf(weapon[2])
var AvgDamage = weaponAverageDamage[weaponIndex]; //required value
```